# Linear regression overfitting and regulization

Tags: regression, lasso, overfitting, ridge-regression

When creating a linear model with many variables, there can be overfitting. Let's say that the training error is 10, and the testing error is 12.

So one can use Ridge or Lasso regression to used the overfitting. Then we have to make sure that the training and testing errors should be similar, to be sure that there is no more overfitting.

What if, in the end, we have the training error and testing error to be equal to 14.

Should we prefer the regulized model without overfitting, or the overfitted linear regression?

Comment: This result is very weird since the unpenalized/unprotected model usually is a special case of the regularized one. Usually the loss function is something like “actual loss + C*regularization” where C is a hyperparameter that you need to tune (it expresses how much emphasis to put on the regularization in comparison to fitting the training data). So for C=0 (or a really small value) you should get the old model back. So I guess that your result tells you that you did something wrong when selecting the right hyperparameter (selecting a hyperparameter can create overfitting as well because...

Comment: the selection strategy becomes part of the mode... that is why we usually need three sets: train train, train test for hyperparameters and validation or whatever you want to call them).